# How many times we can extend the trial version of VS 2010?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I have the trial version of Visual Studio 2010. 60 days ago, I extended the trial version, but now the period is over. I again attempted to extend it, but it is not accepting the key I got from Microsoft. Are we only able to extend the trial one time? Please help me... I dont have VS now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Sounds like you need to download Visual Studio 2010 Express.** There doesn't seem to be any reason to muck about with a free trial if you never intend on paying for the software in the first place.

Find the appropriate version for you, and download it here:
http://www.microsoft.com/express/Downloads/

Answer (score 4):

Well, based on a limited sample size of "you", I would say once. So you may want to consider being less of a cheapskate and going out to buy it.

Seriously, if you've used it for 60 days plus *another* 60 days, you might want to at least *entertain* the idea of beginning to speculate about the merest possibility of actually paying for it (with apologies to Douglas Adams, RIP).

How would you feel if we did that to your software, continuously extending the trial so that you received no economic benefit for your hard-earned yakka?

If you *don't* want to pay for it, there are plenty of free solutions, including Microsoft's own Express editions (or Community editions if you fall into one of the exempted-from-payment categories).

I actually long ago used VS2008 Express because the products I make with it don't make enough money to justify paying for the full version. The Express 2010 editions require registration within 30 days but then no further action after that.

And now, as mentioned, you also have VS2015 Community edition, which I use since I fall into one of those afore-mentioned categories.

I have no qualms about that since Microsoft explicitly allow this. That's not the case with trial software for their professional line of products (otherwise I'd be using them, of course).

Comment: @Pax..one more solution is format the system and reinstall the trail version.. :-p  but i am asking how many times we can extend.. i am not saying i want to extend continuously.. any way thank you

Comment: @Mihir: well, based on experimental evidence, I would say _once._ But that's from a pretty small sample (yourself). Go get their Express edition. You have to register but that's only needed once, then you can use it for as long as you want.

Answer (score 3):

If you are a small business and can't afford to pay full price for Visual Studio, you can spread the cost by subscribing to the MS Action Pack Developer package.

For a mere $375 per year you get:

VS 2010 professional complete and official

Expression Blend too (That one is costy!)

All Office tools for 10 users: thats worth $6500!

All server tools like SQLServer 8, Windows SBS 2008 R2

Plus access to all beta products and online tuition, phone support, you name it.

[Check it here](https://partner.microsoft.com/france/40011340)

Comment: Why are you advertising?

Comment: The answer to your question is incredibly obvious. What you meant to say was "you shouldn't be advertising." Who cares, though? The post is still relevant with helpful information and you don't have to pay him or click the link.